# iOS: event sets propert to nil after timer checks if property is nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, timer

I have a timer that performs an operation on a property if it is not nil, but between checking for nil and performing the operation, an event sets the property to nil.  There are in fact several events all of which could set the property to nil.  There are also other properties that the timer is checking that are in the same boat.

What's the most elegant and scalable way to resolve this?

1. Wrap every use of the property in a synchronized block?
2. Set/release a lock at the beginning of the timer and check wait for the lock in each event?
3. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure on your exact situation but you might want to consider writing a custom setter to the property that will cancel the timer when it is set to nil?

Answer (score 0):

I went with Paul de Lange's answer because it made a lot of sense to me.  I did not want to have to find every place I set the property and wrap it in a `@synchronized` block.

For anyone else who needs to do something similar, here's the code I came up with:

```
@interface MyClass {
//...

//The iVar, note that the iVar has a different name than the property, see the @synthesize command
RefreshOperation *_refreshOperation;

//...
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) RefreshOperation *refreshOperation;

@implementation MyClass

//...

//The timer's callback
- (void)statusTimerEvent:(NSTimer *)aTimer
{
    //Block/wait for thread safe setters/getters
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (self.refreshOperation)
        {
            self.status =  [self.refreshOperation status];
            progressView.progress = self.refreshOperation.progress;
        }
    }
}

//...

//Thread safe setter for the refreshOperation property
- (void)setRefreshOperation:(RefreshOperation *)refreshOperation:(RefreshOperation *)newRefreshOperation
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (_refreshOperation != newRefreshOperation)
        {
            [_refreshOperation release];
            _refreshOperation = [newRefreshOperation retain];
        }
    }
}

//Thread safe getter for the refreshOperation property
- (RefreshOperation *)refreshOperation
{
    id result = nil;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        result = [_refreshOperation retain];
    }
    return [result autorelease];
}

//...

- (void)dealloc
{
    //...

    self.refreshOperation = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

//...

//Connect the property |refreshOperation| to the iVar |_refreshOperation|; having the same name for both results in warning about the local variable hiding a property    
@synthesize refreshOperation = _refreshOperation;
```